# (MySQL) named a database default somehow and cant work with it at all because MySQL workbench thinks im using the default data tyoe

Tags: mysql, sql, database, default

Basically what it sounds like 
[the database is named default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sczmw.png)

which was already there when i made the connection and the tables that are in it are inaccesible.

I've tried moving the tables to another database but mysql doesnt recognize that when i type default i mean the database and not the data type in mysql.

Any help? I goofed somehow and dont know how to fix it and havent found anything else like this problem online.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any [SQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) as an identifier, but you must enclose them in back-ticks:

```
SELECT ... FROM `default`.admin ...
```

It's simpler if you move the tables to another schema that has a name that doesn't conflict with a reserved keyword.

Unfortunately, there's no RENAME SCHEMA statement in MySQL. You have to create a new schema and then RENAME TABLE to move them one by one.

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_awesome_schema;

RENAME TABLE `default`.admin TO my_awesome_schema.admin;
...same for other tables...
```